Simultaneous send and receive (repeater) Bluetooth audio is stutter-y
I'm trying to use a Raspberry Pi as a sort of receiver to manage the several Bluetooth speakers I've accumulated so that I can just connect a (also Bluetooth) audio source like my phone to the Pi and then have the Pi route to a selected speaker.
Out of the box (+ installing PulseAudio's Bluetooth module) bluez seems capable of doing this; I can connect the Pi to a speaker and then my phone to the Pi and PulseAudio will route audio from default source to default sink, but the audio is very stutter-y. I can send test audio to the speaker and it's just fine.
I suspect that somewhere in the Bluetooth stack it's swapping back and forth between send and receive and that's what's introducing the stutter, but I can't find a way to confirm that or any potential solutions (short of a second Bluetooth radio?).
$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller 2C:CF:67:14:1F:AB Pairable: yes
[bluetooth]# devices
Device 00:22:D9:00:1B:6B Audioengine 5+
Device D4:3A:2C:83:C2:78 Pixel 7
[bluetooth]# connect 00:22:D9:00:1B:6B 
Attempting to connect to 00:22:D9:00:1B:6B
[CHG] Device 00:22:D9:00:1B:6B Connected: yes
[NEW] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_22_D9_00_1B_6B/sep7 
[NEW] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_22_D9_00_1B_6B/sep5 
[NEW] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_22_D9_00_1B_6B/sep3 
[NEW] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_22_D9_00_1B_6B/sep1 
[NEW] Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_22_D9_00_1B_6B/sep7/fd0 
Connection successful
[CHG] Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_22_D9_00_1B_6B/sep7/fd0 State: active
[CHG] Device 00:22:D9:00:1B:6B ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_22_D9_00_1B_6B/sep7/fd0 State: idle
[CHG] Device D4:3A:2C:83:C2:78 Connected: yes
[NEW] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/sep1 
[NEW] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/sep2 
[NEW] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/sep3 
[NEW] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/sep4 
[NEW] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/sep5 
[NEW] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/sep6 
[NEW] Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/fd1 
[CHG] Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/fd1 Volume: 0x0066 (102)
[CHG] Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_22_D9_00_1B_6B/sep7/fd0 State: active
[NEW] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 [default]
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Equalizer: off
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Repeat: alltracks
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Shuffle: off
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Scan: off
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Type: Audio
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Subtype: None
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Status: paused
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Name: Bluetooth Player
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Title: I DON'T WANNA TALK
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 TrackNumber: 0x00000001 (1)
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 NumberOfTracks: 0x00000032 (50)
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Duration: 0x00000000 (0)
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Artist: Carter Vail
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Position: 0x00025ae3 (154339)
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Position: 0x00025ae3 (154339)
[CHG] Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_22_D9_00_1B_6B/sep7/fd0 State: idle
[CHG] Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/fd1 State: pending
[CHG] Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/fd1 State: active
[CHG] Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_22_D9_00_1B_6B/sep7/fd0 State: active
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Status: playing
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Position: 0x00026df2 (159218)
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Position: 0x00026e56 (159318)
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Status: paused
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Position: 0x00028872 (166002)
[CHG] Player /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/player0 Position: 0x00028872 (166002)
[CHG] Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_3A_2C_83_C2_78/fd1 State: idle


Does the device use WLAN to establish an Internet connection? To avoid coexistence problems, you should deactivate the WLAN.

That may be contributing, and I found some forum threads where it sounded like it was something of a known issue with the Pi https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=367947. I tried the suggested solution there and it didn't help. Notably, I don't get audio stutter issues when I play a sample .wav file on the Pi out to the BT speaker so I'm not sure it's fully a coexistence issue. Though maybe WiFi + BT transmit + BT receive is sufficient load to cause issues that WiFi + BT transmit don't? I've got a spare Ethernet cable somewhere that I can try this though.

In your scenario, there are at least three Bluetooth participants with two independent frequency and time slot domains, which must be synchronised so that they do not get in each other's way on the repeater device, as this only has one Bluetooth radio hardware. If WLAN also comes around the corner with slot requests because you share an antenna, this is a challenging scenario.
